# Django http404 error urlconf confusion

Tags: django

I was really confused why I was receiving `Http404` error. To be more clear heres my code:

My app named books

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import Http404
from django.template import RequestContext
from books.models import *


def index(request):
    title = 'Book Gallery'
    books = Book.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    lang_list = Lang.objects.all().order_by('-lang')
    template = 'books/index.djhtml'
    context = {'books': books, 'title': title, 'lang_list': lang_list}
    return render_to_response( template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )

def by_book_slug(request, bookslug):
    slug = bookslug
    try:
        book = Book.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except:
        raise Http404

    title = book.name
    template = 'books/singlebook.djhtml'
    context = {'book': book, 'title': title}
    return render_to_response( template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )

def by_lang_slug(request, langslug):
    filter = langslug
    try:
        language = Lang.objects.get(slug=filter)
    except:
        raise Http404
    lang_list = Lang.objects.all().order_by('-lang')
    books = Book.objects.filter(lang=language).order_by('-id')
    title = language
    template = 'books/by_language.djhtml'
    context = {'books': books, 'title': title, 'filter': filter, 'lang_list': lang_list}
    return render_to_response( template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )




urls.py inside my book app folder

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from books import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'(?P<langslug>.*)/$', views.by_lang_slug, name='by_lang'),
    url(r'(?P<bookslug>.*)/$', views.by_book_slug, name='by_book'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='book_gallery'),
)
```

link that pertains to langslug url conf works but those links for bookslug url conf does not work. When I try to switch them down and up, one of them work and the other one is not.

I really don't know what is happening here. Any help will be a great help. Thanks.

the index template of my books app

```
{% extends 'base.djhtml' %}

{% block title %} | Gallery{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
{% endblock %}
{% block content_header %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content_body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <strong>filtered by > 
                {% if filter %}
                    {{ filter }}
                {% else %}
                    All
                {% endif %} 
            </strong>
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li class="nav-header">Filter</li>
              <li class="nav-header
                  {% if not filter %}
                        active
                  {% endif %}
              "><a href="/books/">All</a></li>
              {% for list in lang_list %}
                <li class="nav-header
                    {% if filter == list.slug %}
                        active
                    {% endif %}
                ">
                    <a href="{% url by_lang langslug=list.slug %}">{{ list.lang }}</a>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            {% for book in books %}
                <div class="span3">
                    <a href="{{ book.book_cover.url }}">
                        <img alt="{{book.name}}" src="{{ book.thumbnail.url }}" />
                    </a>
                    <h4>{{book.name}}</h4>
                    <p>{{book.desc|truncatewords:15}}</p>
                    <a href="{% url by_book bookslug=book.slug %}" class="btn btn-mini">View more...</a>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The by_language template for my book app

```
{% extends 'base.djhtml' %}

{% block title %} | Gallery{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
{% endblock %}
{% block content_header %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content_body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <strong>filtered by > 
                {% if filter %}
                    {{ filter }}
                {% else %}
                    All
                {% endif %} 
            </strong>
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li class="nav-header">Filter</li>
              <li class="nav-header
                  {% if not filter %}
                        active
                  {% endif %}
              "><a href="/books">All</a></li>
              {% for list in lang_list %}
                <li class="nav-header
                    {% if filter == list.slug %}
                        active
                    {% endif %}
                ">
                    <a href="{% url by_lang langslug=list.slug %}">{{ list.lang }}</a>
                </li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            {% for book in books %}
                <div class="span3">
                    <a href="{{ book.book_cover.url }}">
                        <img alt="{{book.name}}" src="{{ book.thumbnail.url }}" />
                    </a>
                    <h4>{{book.name}}</h4>
                    <p>{{book.desc|truncatewords:15}}</p>
                    <a href="{% url by_book bookslug=book.slug %}" class="btn btn-mini">View more...</a>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have included a raise `Http404` method when specified slug does not match to any query in the database. The thing I was confused about is, when I try to switch langslug and bookslug urlconf, links that are associated to one of these url works and the other is not.

Comment: in your django shell, try `Book.objects.get(slug=slug)` where slug is the value you are using to test, and see what happens.

Comment: On a side note, `get_object_or_404(Book, slug=slug)` does the same thing as the `try..except` is doing

Comment: I will use get_object_or_404 instead.

Comment: Yes i can retrieve the object using the slug, but in the browser it says the same, http404 error. I can't find where do i made my mistakes.

Comment: I think the problem is in my books.urls , but i can't find what it is.

Comment: The answer posted below makes a lot of sense. Just put the prefix  to urls, and you should be all set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your url, if I put value on it even though they have different view, the result would be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # http://localhost:8000/English/
    url(r'(?P<langslug>.*)/$', views.by_lang_slug, name='by_lang'),

    # http://localhost:8000/YourBook/
    url(r'(?P<bookslug>.*)/$', views.by_book_slug, name='by_book'),

    # http://localhost:8000/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='book_gallery'),
)
```

Have you notice it, they have the same pattern so the first view execute is the `by_lang_slug`. So if you change the order the other one will be executed first. The best thing to do about it is to have `a unique url name`.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # http://localhost:8000/lang/English/
    url(r'lang/(?P<langslug>.*)/$', views.by_lang_slug, name='by_lang'),

    # http://localhost:8000/book/YourBook/
    url(r'book/(?P<bookslug>.*)/$', views.by_book_slug, name='by_book'),

    # http://localhost:8000/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='book_gallery'),
)
```

Now they are different....

Comment: I'm so glad Cath, You have saved me. Thank you so much, I have been thinking of this thing all night long. thank you very much, God Bless

Comment: @DjangoBot If you feel the answer was helpful, be sure to accept it!  Click the check mark next to the answer.